# Issue with Pub Get via dart extension in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I've got a problem where running pub get via the VSCode dart extension doesn't actually get the packages. It doesn't return an error but if I attempt to build my project, it will just continuously tell me my pubspec lock has updated since I last ran pub get.

Running flutter pub get via terminal solves the issue straight way.

Has anyone else experienced this with VSCode?

Comment: you can try by reinstalling those extensions

Answer (score 1):

You can

- delete pubspec.lock

then

- flutter clean
- Reinstall Extensions